# How does is_int look at floatng numbers?

Tags: php

I'm trying to display whole numbers without anything after the decimal point.
I've got a number that is stored as 100.00000.

```
if(is_int($_SESSION['prgoram'][$value]))
```

If if use the above expression to then change the number format, it retunrs fales.

Comment: Because floats are not ints, perhaps you want `is_float()`.

Comment: If you want to *convert* a floating point number to an integer, look at `intval` (or possibly `sprintf` if it's just for display). `is_int` tests whether something is *already* an integer.

Comment: What I'd like to do is look at the number and find if it is a whole number or if there is anything after the decimal point and do a different thing depending on the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare numbers regardless of whether they are float or int, use:

```
if(is_numeric($value))
```

if you want to round the value, use:

```
$newValue = round($value);
```

or

```
$newValue = ceil($value);
```